# html rendering unescaped characters as escaped

Tags: html, html-escape-characters

I am rendering this line of code in a `<pre>` tag to display as normal text on screen:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=7&size=700x540&sensor=false$center=London, England&markers=London, England|Leicester, England|">
```

however it is being misrendered in multiple browsers as:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=7&size=700x540&sensor=false¢er=London, England&markers=London, England|Leicester, England|">
```

Since the escape code for a cent symbol is `&cent;` and not `&cent`, I cannot see why this is happening and there doesn't seem to be any way to prevent it. Can anyone help?

Also, my doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If it makes any difference, this line of code is being added to the document by Javascript's innerHTML method.

Comment: The second line also has an extra `&` between the `540` and the `sensor`. Or is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: copy and paste error - the first line does contain it. Editing the post now..

Comment: Wait wait, is that supposed to be `&sensor=false&center=London, England` instead of `&sensor=false$center=London, England`? Why is there a `$` instead of `&`?

Comment: @Madmartigan: typo! Edited to correct

Comment: Anyway, typos aside, it's _always_ safe to escape your ampersands in attribute values. So just write `src="url?zoom=7&amp;size=700x540&amp;etc"` and it won't go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because something is in a `<pre>` doesn't mean you don't have to escape it (doctype makes no difference here). Any instance of `&` should use the entity `&amp;` if you want `&` to be displayed on screen. You can get away without it sometimes, but that's just the browser being forgiving - you shouldn't take advantage of it. The browser may try to convert to an entity if it recognizes one, even if the semicolon is missing (being forgiving again).

The whole thing (source) should be:

> `<pre>&lt;img src=&quot;http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=7&amp;size=700x540&amp;sensor=false&amp;center=London, England&amp;markers=London, England|Leicester, England|&quot;&gt;</pre>`

By the way, this is true for attribute values too, like `href`. It's common for people to be "lazy" and not escape the ampersands in query strings, but you really should.

Comment: That fixed the issue. I should of seen that much sooner.

Comment: At first it looked like you were saying the browser was converting `$` to `¢`. That I would not have been able to explain. Bad deal for your ecommerce site ;)

Comment: `<pre>` is for preformatted text (preserves line breaks). You might be interested in the `<code>` tag, but there is no such thing as an HTML tag that "breaks out of HTML mode" so to speak, you always need to escape the HTML characters you want displayed.